# Three.js access scene by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I am 6 hours into Three.js and coming to grip with new concepts. I am trying to access the objects inside a scene, on a page with two canvas & scenes.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="my-canvas">
    <canvas width="....></canvas>
</div>

<div id="their-canvas">
    <canvas width="....></canvas>
</div>
```

Each of these containers ends up with a canvas generated inside and some cubes rendered.

I name each scene like this:

```
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.name = sceneName;
```

`sceneName` is a variable containing the name of the scene. I can see the scene property with the correct value when I `console.log` the scene.

Later in the code I want to access a scene by its name, but I have not been successful. What is the correct way?

```
var activeScene = THREE.Object3D.getElementByName(sceneName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method .getElementByName is not a three.js method.
The method .getObjectByName exists in three.js but it wont work in your case because it loops through objects inside a scene (scene is the top-level object).

Solution: Declare a different variable for each scene. Then access each scene by its variable name.

For example:

```
var my_scene = new THREE.Scene();
var their_scene = new THREE.Scene();

// assign to another variable
var activeScene = their_scene;
// and later
activeScene = my_scene;
```